# ASP .NET Core 2.1 Razor Pages anchor tag helper generates empty href for asp-route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My anchor tag helpers generate empty href when using asp-route attribute. I'm sure I'm missing something.

Startup -> ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddRouting();
services.AddMvc()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/user/signin", "signin");
            })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Then in razor view:

```html
 <a asp-route="signin">Sign In</a>
```

Which generates

```html
<a href="">Sign In</a>
```

If I navigate to /signin it goes correctly to /user/signin page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `asp-route` tag-helper expects the provided value to be a [named route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.1#asp-route):

> The asp-route attribute is used for creating a URL linking directly to a named route.

If you want to link to an ASP.NET Core Razor Page, you can use `asp-page`:

```html
<a asp-page="/user/signin">Sign In</a>
```

This will generate something like the following:

```html
<a href="/signin">Sign In</a>
```

Comment: So asp-route requires the Route attribute decoration ? I made a test now and added [Route("/user/signin", Name = "signin")] to the OnGetAsync and then <a asp-route="signin"... and it still generates empty href.

Comment: I don't think ASP.NET Core Razor Pages support using `[Route]` or e.g. `[HttpGet]`. There's a discussion around this [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6605) that *suggests* my understanding is correct.

Comment: Thank you, seems that RedirectToRoute also doesn't work in Razor Pages, it doesn't take into consideration the routes defined via options.Conventions.AddPageRoute

Comment: You'll want to use `RedirectToPage` for that, with a value similar to my example.

Comment: The RedirectToPage and the asp-page worked for me. I just thought that RedirectToRoute and the asp-route  would be a more appropriate way when using routes, but now its clear that they can be used only with MVC and not supported by Razor Pages.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using a [razor](/questions/tagged/razor) webapp projct `dotnet new webapp` with [asp.net-core](/questions/tagged/asp.net-core).

My page structure is this

```
/Pages/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Admin/Orders/OrderList.cshtml
/Pages/Admin/Orders/OrderDetail.cshtml
```

From `OrderList.cshtml` i want to link to `OrderDetail.cshtml` and pass the `OrderId` to the page `OrderDetail.cshtml`. Inside the page `OrderList.cshtml` i added

```html
<!-- /Pages/Admin/Orders/OrderList.cshtml -->
<a asp-page="/Admin/Orders/OrderDetail"  
               asp-route-id="@order.OrderId">@order.OrderId</a>
```

The `href` has only a value if the path is correct. My mistake was to use `~/Admin/...` (wrong) instead of `/Admin/...` (correct)